# Как выбрать записи, у которых в поле date завтрашняя дата?

Tags: sql

Мне нужно оповестить клиентов за день до начала игры, т.е., выбрать запросом все записи, у которых дата - следующий день (00:00-24:00).

Вот такой запрос выбирает записи предыдущего дня:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE meta_value BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE()"
```

Пробовал играться с ним, что-то не работает.

Так тоже не получается:

```
SELECT FROM table WHERE meta_value BETWEEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

Нашел:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE meta_value > NOW() AND meta_value < NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Как поясняет мануал](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between), выражение

```
expr BETWEEN min AND max
```

эквивалентно

```
min <= expr AND expr <= max
```

Если взять за рассмотрение `2018-10-18` (завтра), то получает вы запрашиваете

```
'2018-10-18' <= '2018-10-18' and '2018-10-18' <= '2018-10-17'
```

Второе условие ожидаемо невозможно. Проще говоря, вы как минимум перепутали аргументы местами.

---

Если ваше поле `meta_value` типа `date`, то вам достаточно строгого сравнения:

```
where meta_value = (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Если это `timestamp` или `datetime` - то интересный вопрос, откуда именно считать следующий день. Сутки от времени запуска запроса? Тогда:

```
where meta_value between now() and now() + interval 1 day
```

Следующие календарные сутки? Тогда:

```
where meta_value >= curdate() + interval 1 day and  meta_value < curdate() + interval 2 day
```

(следующие сутки - это время начиная от завтра (+1 день) и завершая послезавтра(+2 дня), но не захватывая их - потому between здесь не подходит)

PS: вы можете встретить возможность сделать `where date(meta_value) = curdate() + INTERVAL 1 DAY` - обратите внимание, что этот запрос даст корректный результат, но не может использовать индекс по meta_value.

Comment: Спасибо, нашел сам